# Continuity of a Linear Functional

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, functions, normed-spaces

I am trying to prove that, given a normed linear space $X$, a real-valued functional $p$ is continuous iff for any constant $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, the sets $\{x\in X : p(x) > \lambda\}$ and $\{x\in X : p(x) < \lambda\} $ are open. I have a intuitive idea in my head as to why this is true but I'm struggling to formulate it strictly on paper. How would I go about this?

Comment: Could you please explain what your intuitive idea is? I know you said it's hard to write it formally, but if you try to explain it, the process of doing so may help you find the answer for yourself! :)

Comment: Note that you can also work directly from the definition of continuity, which says that a function is continuous iff the preimage of every open set is open.

Comment: You might have been distracted by irrelevant hypotheses. Given any topological space $X$, a real-valued function $p$ on $X$ is continuous iff, for any constant $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, the sets $\{x\in X:p(x)>\lambda\}$ and $\{x\in X:p(x)<\lambda\}$ are open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what follows, I will explore the fact that $p : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous iff $\forall \ V$ open in $X$, $\ p^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$.

First, we prove $p$ continuous $\Longrightarrow$ $\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, \{x \in X : p(x) > \lambda\}$ and $\{x \in X : p(x) < \lambda\}$ are open.

Note that the sets $]-\infty, \lambda[$ and $]\lambda, \infty[$ are open in $\mathbb{R}$. By coninuity of $p$, we get that $\ p^{-1}\bigl(]-\infty,\lambda[\bigr) = \{x \in X : p(x) < \lambda\}$ is open in $X$.

Analogously, we get that $\ p^{-1}\bigl(]\lambda, \infty[\bigr) = \{x \in X : p(x) > \lambda\}$ is open in $X$.

Now, we prove $\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, \{x \in X : p(x) > \lambda\}$ and $\{x \in X : p(x) < \lambda\}$ are open $\Longrightarrow$ $p$ continuous.

Fix $\epsilon > 0$ arbitrary and observe that $]p(x) - \epsilon, \ p(x) + \epsilon[ = ]-\infty, \ p(x) + \epsilon[ \ \cap \ ]p(x) - \epsilon, \ \infty[$.

We then get $p^{-1}\bigl(]p(x) - \epsilon, \ p(x) + \epsilon[\bigl) = p^{-1}\bigl(]-\infty, \ p(x) + \epsilon[\bigr) \ \cap \ p^{-1}\bigl(]p(x) - \epsilon, \ \infty[\bigr)$ is open, since the intersection of open sets is open. Morevor, because $p^{-1}\bigl(]p(x) - \epsilon, \ p(x) + \epsilon[\bigl)$ contains $x$, $\exists \ \delta > 0$ such that $B_X(x,\delta) \subseteq p^{-1}\bigl(B_{\mathbb{R}}(p(x), \epsilon)\bigr)$, where $B_X(x,\delta)$ is the open ball in $X$ centered in $x$ with radius $\delta$ and $B_{\mathbb{R}}(p(x), \epsilon)$ is the open ball in $\mathbb{R}$ centered in $p(x)$ with radius $\epsilon$.